# Entity Framework 4 - Not generating associations with MySQL

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4, MySQL 5.5 and Connector Net 6.3.6.   The EF entity generator is not creating any of my foreign keys. I've tried setting this up with several types, normal, unique, etc.  It generates them fine with SQL Server, but fails with MySQL.

Any suggestions?